# DeleteInterpProc called with active evals

Tags: c++, tcl

I am writing a program which executes tcl scripts. When the script has `exit` command, the program crashes with this error

```
DeleteInterpProc called with active evals
Aborted
```

I am calling `Tcl_EvalFile(m_interpreter, script.c_str())` where script is the file name.
Also I have tried `Tcl_Eval` with arguments interpreter and "source filename". Result is the same. Other tcl comands (eg. puts) interpreter executes normally. How this can be fixed?

```
#include <tcl.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    Tcl_Interp *interp = Tcl_CreateInterp(); 

    //Tcl_Preserve(interp);

    Tcl_Eval (interp, "exit");

    //Tcl_Release(interp);

    std::cout << "11111111111" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This is the simple case. "11111111111" are not printed. As I understand whole program is exited when calling `Tcl_Eval (interp, "exit");`. The result is same after adding `Tcl_Preserve` and `Tcl_Release`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the interpreter, the execution context for Tcl code, is getting its feet deleted out from under itself; this makes it very confused! At least you're getting a clean panic/abort rather than a disgusting hard-to-reproduce crash.

The easiest fix is probably to do:

```
Tcl_Preserve(m_interpreter);
// Your code that calls Tcl_EvalFile(m_interpreter, script.c_str())
// and deals with the results.
Tcl_Release(m_interpreter);
```

Be aware that after the `Tcl_Release`, the `Tcl_Interp` handle may refer to deleted memory.
(Yes, wrapping the `Tcl_Preserve`/`Tcl_Release` in RAII goodness is reasonable.)

---

If you want instead to permit your code to run after the script does an `exit`, you have to take additional steps. In particular, the standard Tcl `exit` command is not designed to cause a return to the calling context: it *will* cause the process to call the `_exit(2)` system call. To change it's behavior, replace it:

```
// A callback function that implements the replacement
static int
MyReplacementExit(ClientData unused, Tcl_Interp *interp, int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    // We ought to check the argument count... but why bother?
    Tcl_DeleteInterp(interp);
    return TCL_OK;
}

int main() {
    Tcl_Interp *interp = Tcl_CreateInterp(); 

    // Install that function over the standard [exit]
    Tcl_CreateCommand(interp, "exit", MyReplacementExit, NULL, NULL);

    // Important; need to keep the *handle* live until we're finished
    Tcl_Preserve(interp);

    // Or run whatever code you want here...
    Tcl_Eval(interp, "exit");

    // Important piece of cleanup code
    if (!Tcl_InterpDeleted(interp))
        Tcl_DeleteInterp(interp);
    Tcl_Release(interp);
    // After this point, you *MUST NOT* use interp

    std::cout << "11111111111" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The rules for doing memory management in these sorts of scenarios are laid out in [the manual page for `Tcl_CreateInterp`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/CrtInterp.htm#M6). (That's the 8.6 manual page, but the relevant rules have been true since at least Tcl 7.0, which is over 2 decades ago.) Once an interpreter is deleted, you can no longer count on executing any commands or accessing any variables in it; the Tcl library handles the state unwinding for you.

Answer (score 1):

It might be better to replace (hide) the `exit` command and create your own `exit` command that exit your program gracefully. I'm not that good with C and the Tcl C Api, but I hope this can help you.

Eggdrop for example uses the `die` command to exit gracefully.